# Seq.find crashes for large numbers (int64)

Tags: f#, sequence

I have the following F# code, which should find the smallest prime factor of a given number x:

```
let smallestFactor x : int64 = 
    [2L .. x] |> Seq.find( fun s -> x % s = 0L )
```

However, when I call the function with a large number, e.g. 600851475143 my Visual Studio takes some GB of memory and all CPU power and never returns.
I start the code via JetBrains ReSharper as a unit test which is written in C#:

```
[Test]
public void SmallestFactorOf600851475143()
{
    var result = Problem3.smallestFactor( 600851475143 );
}
```

My F# code and the number are part of a solution for [problem 3, Euler Project](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3)

I am just starting with F#. Is there an obvious problem with my code?

Comment: Change list to sequence: instead of [...] use {...}.

Comment: @EugeneFotin thanks a lot, you can make that comment an answer :)

Comment: The reason why this happens is because `[ 2L .. x]` creates an in-memory linked list of all the numbers before it runs the `Seq.find` operation. When `x` is large then that linked list takes lots of memory. A sequence, on the other hand, doesn't have to create all its items beforehand; it will only have to allocate enough memory to handle the *current* item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as already mentioned, expression `[2L .. x]` creates list, and for x = 600851475143 it allocates 600851475143 * 8 ~ 4,806 GB, so that's why it doesn't works. What you do really want, is to iterate through all numbers, so sequence will work perfectly for you:

```ml
let smallestFactor x : int64 = 
    seq {2L .. x} |> Seq.find( fun s -> x % s = 0L )
```